# Compress-Archive handle files with same name in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm writing an archiving script which collecting desired files to an array then adding them to an archive 1 by 1.

I came to a problem when there is DIR1/file.ext and DIR2/file.ext because DIR2's file going to overwrite the previous.

How can I set unique filename or how it's possible to solve it on the fly instead of copying files to a dir with structures then zip the whole dir?

Here is my code:

```
# GET FILE LIST
$outgoingfiles =  Get-ChildItem -Depth 1 -Filter "*.EXT" | Where-Object { $_.DirectoryName -like "*OUTGOING*" }

# Handle if OUTGOING/archive dir is exists
if(-not (Test-Path "OUTGOING/archive")) {
       New-Item -Path "OUTGOING/archive" -ItemType Directory 
}

# ZIP outgoing files
ForEach ($outgoing in $outgoingfiles) {
    Compress-Archive $outgoing.FullName -Update -DestinationPath $zippath
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are the file names important at all - eg. do they need to be preserved?

Comment: So from my understanding, you want to copy all same name files to a flat directory without preserving folders, but you want make sure the files don't overwrite each other.

Comment: Original filename must be kept but it can extended for example with the original parent dir so DIR1\file.ext can be dir1_file.ext in the archive. Preserving directories in the archive also good.

Comment: I guess the other way is embedding timestamps into the filename, but that could be risky because two files could have been created at the same time.

Comment: How can I manipulate filename in the archive at this code?

`Compress-Archive $outgoing.FullName -Update -DestinationPath $zippath`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just copy the files along with their parent directories to a destination folder, then zip it up with `Compress-Archive`. Then you don't have to worry about making filenames unique.

**Demo:**

```
$sourceFolder = "C:\\"
$destinationFolder = "C:\\OUTGOING"

# Create destination folder if it doesn't exist
if (-not(Test-Path -Path $destinationFolder -PathType Container))
{
    New-Item -Path $destinationFolder -ItemType Directory
}

# Get all .exe files one level deep
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Depth 1 -Filter *.ext

foreach ($file in $files)
{
    # Get standalone parent directory e.g. DIR1, DIR2
    $parentFolder = Split-Path -Path (Split-Path -Path $file.FullName) -Leaf

    # Create destination path with this parent directory
    $destination = Join-Path -Path $destinationFolder -ChildPath $parentFolder

    # Create destination parent directory if it doesn't exist
    if (-not(Test-Path -Path $destination -PathType Container))
    {
        New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory
    }

    # Copy file to parent directory in destination
    Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $destination
}

# Zip up destination folder
# Make sure to pass -Update for redoing compression
Compress-Archive -Path $destinationFolder -DestinationPath "OUTGOING.zip" -Update -CompressionLevel Optimal
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to tell `Compress-Archive` to rename files when a file with the same name is already included in the zip.

What you can do is create a temporary folder, copy all files to there and if needed rename them. Then create the zip file using the unique files in that folder.
Finally, remove the temp folder again:

```
$zippath  = 'D:\Test\OutGoing.zip'  # path and filename for the output zip file
$rootPath = 'D:\Test'               # where the files can be found

# create a temporary folder to uniquely copy the files to
$tempFolder = Join-Path -Path ([System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath()) -ChildPath ([Guid]::NewGuid().Guid)
$null = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $tempFolder
# create a hashtable to store the fileHash already copied
$fileHash = @{}

# get the list of files and copy them to a temporary folder
Get-ChildItem -Path $rootPath -Depth 1 -Filter '*.EXT' -File | Where-Object { $_.DirectoryName -like "*OUTGOING*" } | ForEach-Object {
    $count = 1
    $newName = $_.Name
    # test if the file name is already in the hash and if so, append a counter to the basename
    while ($fileHash.ContainsKey($newName)) {
        $newName = "{0}({1}){2}" -f $_.BaseName, $count++, $_.Extension
    }
    # store this file name in the hash and copy the file
    $fileHash[$newName] = $true
    $newFile = Join-Path -Path $tempFolder -ChildPath $newName
    $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $newFile -Force
}

# append '*.*' to the temporary folder name.
$path = Join-Path -Path $tempFolder -ChildPath '*.*'
# next, get the list of files in this temp folder and start archiving
Compress-Archive -Path $path -DestinationPath $zippath -Update

# when done, remove the tempfolder and files
Remove-Item -Path $tempFolder -Force -Recurse
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I like this answer. Shows how to make the filenames unique, which is a good way to do it if my *lazier* approach is not sufficient. +1